# Difference between using getter and setter methods to add list to a bean property?

Tags: java, collections, javabeans

Is there any difference between these two ways of adding a list to the bean property?

```
private List<String> stringList;

public List<String> getStringList() {
    return stringList;
}

public void setStringList(final List<String> stringList) {
    this.stringList = stringList;
}
```

1. `setStringList(list of strings)`
2. `getStringList().addAll(list of strings)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the list would already contain entries, those would be overwritten with method 1, because you set a completely new instance of the list.

With method 2, you would just add all new entries to the already existing list instance.

Comment: And you get a NPE with 2 if the list `stringList` isn't already initialized

Answer (score 0):

In first method , the whole of `stringList` is initialized with provided list .
But in second method , all the elements of new list are added to existing `stringList` .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a big difference, and first approach is correct. Here's why:

- It's a setter method and hence, it should `set` the list rather than adding the elements. If you want to `add`, you can expose another method like `addStrings()`
- Second approach would keep on adding the elements to the same list, i.e. if it's called 10 times with a list of 10 elements, the resultant list will have 100 elements which is not desirable
- Second approach will throw a `NullPointerException` if the list is `null` (which it probably will be, if the object is newly created and the `list` is not assigned any value)

Read more on `getters` and `setters` [here](http://www.codejava.net/coding/java-getter-and-setter-tutorial-from-basics-to-best-practices).